# facebook like button not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have a problem with my facebook like button. Basically I have an ajax gallery on my page and so when the image changes I change my facebook button so that the button represents the url to the new image. But when I click share it just shares the original url even though it has changed. Here is an example:

When page loads the code for the facebook button is:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 80px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://go-style.co.uk/test-gallery/&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe>
```

I then use jQuery to change the code to this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; width: 80px; height: 21px;" allowtransparency="true" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A//go-style.co.uk/nggallery/page-7029/image/30&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80&amp;action=like&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;colorscheme=light"></iframe>
```

Yet clicking on the new button likes the original url

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I then use jQuery - can you show this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a caching issue with facebook in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried refreshing the iframe after changing it SRC?

```
$('#youriframe').attr("src", $('#youriframe').attr("src"));
```

Comment: yeah instead of changing its src i just insert a whole new iframe with the new src.